# Recover deleted disk (diskpart clean) which was protected with bitlocker

Tags: protected, data-recovery

I am in big trouble I have a western digital disk with 2 drives which contained all my digital life.

I mistakenly used clean command in diskpart and cleaned the disk one of the drives (900GB) were protected by bitlocker I used Windows 8 to protect it and the other one was unprotected (30GB).

Now I want to know how to recover the partition or data I have already used Recover My files and Partition Table doctor without luck.

I do have password for the protected drive but not the key.

Comment: Data recovery is simple with unencrypted discs. The filesystem itself is NTFS?

Comment: Did you do a clean (in which case all might not be lost) or a clean all (which is a secure erase and you are stuffed if you don't have backups ?)

Comment: Have a look at photorec (I've used this and its read-only, takes a long time but will recover files of known types - but not filenames or directory structure if they exist), and testdisk (which I have not used, but sounds like the kind of program you want to use to attempt to recover from partitioning problems)

Comment: Thanks for the info no it I used clean only I tried few but they are only able to recover data from unencrypted drive I had partitioned the disk into 2 drives the other drive which was encrypted using Windows 8 I want to know how to recover that one? I do have the password for me but not the key.

Comment: @user2183633 please use comments to get clarification or respond to other people's comments. You can also [edit] your question to add more information. Answers should only be posted as a solution to the question. See the [FAQ] and [about] for more info.